# Error using SCP: "not a regular file"

Tags: scp

I have been searching for a while and I can't find the definition of a regular file. My path is permanent (I start at `/`) and I am connecting to

```
scp root@IP: /path/to/picture.jpg
```

Results in an inquiry for a password and then...

```
scp: .: not a regular file
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A regular file is a file that isn't a directory or more exotic kinds of [“special” files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types) such as named pipes, devices, sockets, doors, etc. [Symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) are not regular files either, but they behave like their target when it an application is accessing the content of the file.

You passed `root@IP:` as the source of the copy and `/path/to/picture.jpg` as the destination. The source is the home directory of the user `root` on the machine `IP`. This is useful as a destination, but not as a source. What you typed required to copy a directory onto a file; `scp` cannot copy a directory unless you ask for a recursive copy with the `-r` option (and it would refuse to overwrite an existing file with a directory even with `-r`, but it would quietly overwrite a regular file if the source was a regular file).

If `/path/to/picture.jpg` is the path on the remote machine of the file you want to copy, you need to stick the file name to the host specification. It's the colon `:` that separates the host name from the remote path. You'll need to specify a destination as well.

```
scp root@IP:/path/to/picture.jpg /some/destination
```

If you want to copy the local file `/path/to/picture.jpg` to the remote host, you need to swap the arguments. Unix copy commands put the source(s) first and the destination last.

```
scp /path/to/picture.jpg root@IP:
```

If you want to copy the remote file `/path/to/picture.jpg` to the same location locally, you need to repeat the path. You can have your shell does the work of repeating for you (less typing, less readability).

```
scp root@IP:/path/to/picture.jpg /path/to/picture.jpg
scp {root@IP:,}/path/to/picture.jpg
```

Comment: make sure no spaces exist between the hostname and file

Comment: I feel so incredibly silly after reading this. source, destination! Duh!

Answer (score 216):

When copying a directory, you should use the `-r` option:

```
scp -r root@IP:/path/to/file /path/to/filedestination
```

Answer (score 12):

You are getting that error because you are trying to copy a folder and not file and hence you should copy your files recursively by using `-r` option

Use below command when copying files from remote machine to local machine

```
scp -r root@RemoteIP:/path/to/file /path/to/filedestination
```

OR

When copying files from local machine to remote machine

```
scp -r /path/to/file root@RemoteIP:/path/to/filedestination
```

Answer (score 5):

syntax issue - remove the white space between

> root@IP:

and

> /path

Comment: But, then you don't have a target for `scp` anymore.

Comment: yup. i pressed enter too quickly and lack the rep to fix it. surprised i can even comment here. cheers.

Comment: I think you can always comment to your own contributions, and I thought you could also always edit them?

Comment: I don't thik that can cause this error `not a regular file`

Comment: @hisi use ```-r``` as scp argument.

Answer (score 4):

`scp root@IP:/path/to/file /path/to/filedestination`

Above command copies a file from remote server to your computer. If you type only `scp root@IP:` it will try to copy the home directory of root (scp users home `.`).

So you need to provide the exact path to the file

Comment: This worked. Thanks a bunch, man. Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

```
scp root@IP:/path/to/*.jpg  /path/to/filedestination/
```

This will work(at least on my Mac)

Answer (score 0):

This is late answer, but I hope this will help someone who got my issue.

I also got same issue when try to upload a zip file to a remote server.

My problem was, I missed `:` , what I had used is : `scp myfile.zip remoteuser@IP/destination/folder`

It should be `scp myfile.zip remoteuser@IP:/destination/folder`