# "not regular file" when trying to scp .gitignore file

Tags: terminal, osx, git, scp

The remote directory already contains a .gitignore file, which I want to overwrite and upload a new one. After doing:

```
scp -P[portnumber] root@domain.com:path/for/file/ location/of/file/.gitignore
```

I received the following message:

```
not a regular file
```

What do I need to do to copy the "not regular file" as well as overwrite the existing one? I'm assuming this question is very basic considering that I can't find the answer anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: I have read the following, similar question but it doesn't fully answer my question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52634/error-using-scp-not-a-regular-file

Comment: The syntax is `scp <source> <destination>`. Did you mean to copy from `location/of/file/.gitignore` to within `root@domain.com:path/for/file/`? If so, you should reverse the order of parameters.

Comment: I was answering my own question while you were adding this comment. This was actually the source of the problem and if I had known it was that simple, I wouldn't have posted. Sorry! Thanks so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file from a remote server to a local machine?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I had my location and destination backwards. I changed it to:

```
scp -P[portnumber] /path/to/.gitignore root@domain.com:/path/to/destination
```

That worked!